# US B1/B2 Visa interview wait times - what is Waiver Visitor in this context?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program

In looking up the potential wait times for a B1/B2 visa interview, at [Visa Appointment Wait Times](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html), I'm presented with a table of different wait times for different types of visa interview appointments.

[image]

I see there are some options including "Required" and some including "Waiver" - what do these Required and Waiver mean in this context?

Is this along the lines of whether people would normally qualify for the VWP?  Or is this something completely different?

Comment: Your red box has ignored the first word of the phrase, which is either "interview required" or "interview waiver."  It's confusing that they don't use the same part of speech.  It would be less so if they said "interview waived," for example.

Comment: @phoog Yes that makes sense now thanks to the links in the answers and your earlier comment.  I had read that being "Waiver Visitor" and "Required Visitor" (which I thought meant Visa Required visitor - ie couldn't use VWP), but I see what they're saying now!

Comment: Indeed, at first I was even more confused, because isn't the main point of the VWP to avoid having to visit the consulate altogether?  Then I realized what it was all about. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a few different statements about interview waivers.

1. If under 14 or over 79.
2. visa renewal (with extra requirements like no refusal on most recent visa, and so on)
3. Connected to 2, certain categories of visas (like student or C/D visas) with different embassies allowing different categories of visas to have interviews waived.

[Burma's embassy](https://mm.usembassy.gov/visas/u-s-embassy-rangoon-interview-waiver-guidelines-iwp/) has a comprehensive page about the different categories and what documents, etc. that you still have to have or submit. The [Indian embassy](https://in.usembassy.gov/visas/frequently-asked-questions/) has a slightly different statement about which visa categories are eligible.

And here's the [Canadian one](https://ca.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-renewal-by-mail/).

Comment: Thanks for this.  My specific inquiry would be for Mexico, but I can't seem to find matching pages for Mexico - do you know if the same waivers might apply for visas issued in Mexico?  (I know my screenshot in the question says Quebec, but I had been going through embassies/consulates in both Mexico and Canada trying to find one with shorter wait times!)

Comment: It's an "interview waiver," not a "visa waiver."  That is, there are two orthogonal parameters, one being the group of visa classes (visitor, student, worker) and the other being "interview required" vs "interview waiver."  Together, these yield six categories.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is referring to whether an interview is required or waived.

https://mx.usembassy.gov/status-of-u-s-consular-operations-in-mexico-in-light-of-covid-19/

> The U.S. Embassy and Consulates in Mexico are currently processing
> nonimmigrant visas.  Applicants should expect a longer-than-normal
> wait time for this service and plan accordingly.  For more information
> about wait times, visit this link .  **Applicants applying in the same
> visa class and whose previous visa expired within the last 48 months
> may be eligible for interview waiver**.  Applicants may schedule a
> renewal appointment here .